# Spring-security split authentication and the authorization

Tags: apache-flex, authentication, spring-security, blazeds

I'm trying to create a custom login for my flex web app with spring-security.
I have an working version where we use the channelset.login with blazeds.

The problem i have is that i would like to split the authentication and the authorization.

I would like to ask the user to make some choices after the authentication to determine its roles.

Since the roles the user is authorized to are determined by this choices.

This means the user has to be authenticated and then the client needs to do a service call to the service and then the authorization process needs to take place.

Does anyone know if this is possible and have some tips of how this can be done?

Thanks in advance,

Arjen

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that doesn't sound too far-fetched.
You can store the user roles in the database, make each role for new users something like SIGNUP which will only allow the user to signup, once his new role is determined, simply update that role and restrict the new role from being able to update the role again, unless you're admin.

You can also override the authentication process to do whatever you want to do: http://mark.koli.ch/2010/07/spring-3-and-spring-security-setting-your-own-custom-j-spring-security-check-filter-processes-url.html

The session object might need to be refreshed if you're using some form of ORM.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. But the problem is not for new users who want to sign up. Every time a user logs in he gets some choices. An example is that he has to choose a customer. Depending on the customer he can get the roles which this customer has configured. So after the username is checked and authenticated i need to go back to the client ask the user for the customer. Than the client sends the customer back to the server and there the roles are selected from the database.

Comment: That should still work, just allow whichever role the user switches to to be able to switch to another role. 
Roles are just strings which means you can assign any role to any user.

Comment: Oke, I will have a look at this. I tried to change the roles in one of my services but spring returned an error saying that the roles list cannot be changed.